# $T^2$ is the identity operator. Then $V$ is the direct sum of of eigenspaces $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(-1)}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $T$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. If $T^2$ is the identity operator, how can I prove that V is the direct sum of of eigenspaces $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(-1)}$?

Answer (score 4):

If $T^2$ is the identity operator, V is the direct sum of of eigenspaces $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(-1)}$. Indeed every vector of $V$ can be written as : $$v= \frac {v-T(v)}{2}+\frac {v+T(v)}{2}$$ note that $\frac  {v-T(v)}{2}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$ while $\frac {v+T(v)}{2}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. This show that $T$ is diagonalizable